# Custom hook for reac-query CRUD opertions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm working on encapsulating my `react-query` CRUD operations for Orders in a custom hook. First I've encapsulated the `getAllOrders` opertion and worked well but now I'm trying to do the same with the `getDetails` and I'm having this error message:

> React Hook "useQuery" is called in function "order" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

It's complaining because the query it's not being executed on a component or hook but inside a function inside a hook.

I don't want to pass a parameter to the hook because not always I'll need one order details.

This is my hook so far:

```js
const useOrders = () => {
  const session = useContext(Context);
  const token = session.storedValue.token;

  const orders = useQuery(["orders", token], () => {
    const result = getOrders(token);
    return result;
  });

  const order = (orderId) => {
    const query = useQuery(["order", token, orderId], () => {
      const result = getOrderDetails(token, orderId);
      return result;
    });

    return query;
  };

  return { orders, order };
};
```

I'd like to pass the `orderId` to the `order` function and get query.

Answer (score 2):

## It looks like 2 separate hooks to me

Be more definite when calling hooks, sometimes you want all orders and sometimes you search for one. make these 2 different hooks for use as required

```
const useOrders = () => {
  const session = useContext(Context);
  const token = session.storedValue.token;

  const orders = useQuery(["orders", token], () => {
    const result = getOrders(token);
    return result;
  });
  return orders;
};

const useOrder = (orderId) => {
  const session = useContext(Context);
  const token = session.storedValue.token;
  const order = useQuery(["order", token, orderId], () => {
    const result = getOrderDetails(token, orderId);
    return result;
  });

  return order;
};
```

Comment: Yes I was checking react-query docs and found this example https://codesandbox.io/s/45dqt?file=/src/hooks/usePost.js and they follow the same strategy